10 µF and 0.1 µF capacitors not making any difference in filtering out noise
I have two circuits (green and brown) featuring a load cell, HX711, and ESP32-C3:

The HX711 and ESP32-C3 go on top of those round female pin header.
The only difference between them is that one is using a 10 µF capacitor and 0.1 µF capacitor, which are connected to the VCC and GND of the HX711. People suggested I do this to keep the noise from the ESP32-C3 from distorting the load cell readings (especially when the ESP32-C3 connects to Wi-Fi.)
These are the readings of both circuits with no load applied (and with the ESP32-C3 connected to Wi-Fi and sending POST requests):

(Y = deviation from 0 in grams, X: the reading number.)
I think that variance is normal. Am I wrong? I'm confused. How come the capacitors aren't making any difference in my circuits?
Also posted here.

It's impossible to draw any useful conclusion from 10 samples with unknown period between them - think of it as "extreme aliasing", the signal could be doing anything between the samples. You'd be much better off trying to use (borrow?) an oscilloscope to actually inspect the signals.

If the capacitors you're referring to are on the perfboard, then they're likely the wrong choice (high ESR for the electrolytic), and too far away (long legs, pin interconnects) to be useful.

@Attie The oscilloscope readings look almost the same. 3V3 and GND. Circuit: https://i.sstatic.net/oRsxJjA4.png. Circuit with caps: https://i.sstatic.net/JpvTHec2.png. But since the readings are almost the same, the noise should also be pretty much the same?

@Attie Sorry, but the capacitors are as close to the 3V3 and GND of the HX711 as they can be (the HX711 goes on top of those round female pin headers). Or you mean the electrolytic capacitor shouldn't be behind the ceramic one? Or you meant too far away from the ESP32-C3?

Doesn't the HX711 already include it's own very high PSRR regulator onboard? If so I'd expect additional filtering to make little difference.

Both boards have already 10uF capacitors that probably are sufficient for the few tests that you did.  Maybe an additional one is not needed 99% of the time, but could be that time to time the ESP32 needs more power than normal, the supply is not responding fast enough and the wind is blowing from the north. Then to have an additional cap close to the board could help. Or maybe is never needed.

@Gos Sorry, by board, you mean the ESP32 or HX711?

The HX711, that I suppose that could be more affected by power disturbances produced by the ESP32 when there is high WIFI activity or whatever. Could be that the onboard capacitors are enough, but to add another one just in case will not hurt.

"the capacitors are as close to the 3V3 and GND of the HX711 as they can be" - no, they're electrically quite far away, and on an entirely different PCB!

I didn't mention earlier, but are you confident that these variants are actually above the typical / intrinsic accuracy you'd expect from your sensors, wiring, and HX711? Perhaps power has nothing to do with this...

Having recently tried out the HX711, I can say with some confidence these errors are well within the typical noise floor for load Cells designed for > 10 kg. If you're using a much smaller load cell, then I would have to go and check, but I still suspect your problem has nothing to do with decoupling whatsoever.

If you look closely there are already decoupling capacitors on the HX711 board, adding to the protoboard probably doesn't help much if you don't know what kind of noise you are dealing with. BTW, the wires on EE, BB and AA better to be twrist-pair than some random wire dangling around that would pickup the noise on the input of HX711.

I run my HX711 with a MCU running at 5MHz, not only be able to run on a coin cell battery, and with very low noise generated by the MCU. You are using an ESP32-C3 which has clock of 160MHz, plus WiFI/Bluetooth that all generates a lot of noise, this is why it is important to use the right MCU for the right application, not to pick the fastest and newsiest available in the market... If you don't need wifi, turn it off, run at 40Mhz. You can also do some simply band-pass filtering with software, read 10 readings, sort them out from low to high, and sum-up the middle 4 readings and divide by 4.

@hcheung Thansk for the suggestion. I do need Wi-Fi (I want to send the readings to the cloud). And I think the ESP32-C3 is the cheapest alternative.

You still be able to use WiFi if you run 80MHz instead of 160MHz, also turn off WiFi when you are doing measurement and only turn on WiFi when you need to send data. It will be less noisy.

@hcheung Sorry, you meant I should configure the ESP32-C3 so that it uses 80MHz instead of 160MHz? Or you're suggesting I get a MCU of 80MHz that also has Wi-Fi?

80MHz is the minimum required for WiFi to work, it more than sufficient to handle the HX711, and this will reduce the noise slightly as well as power consumption... This is what I would do... Just change the frequency from the IDE pulldown menu.

@hcheung Thanks a lot for all the great advice!

Decoupling capacitors are important. And they are a cargo cult. We put them in in the hopes that they prevent us from having problems. And they can do the job. You'll just never know if you needed all of them or even if you needed them at all (which is also a bit of a prevention paradox).
Also, measuring noise sometimes borders on black magic. Noise is really hard to measure. It's even harder to measure the results of noise because there could be countless other factors influencing the result.
So, decoupling parts with digital signals is always a good idea. Seeing a result is mostly a question of statistics. Statistics with many measurments over bigger spans of time. Eight measurements is by far not enough: I'd suggest to go to at least 1000 and do some statistical analysis if you want to get a usable result.
It's very well possible that you won't see a difference. But you can be almost 100% sure that you'll see a difference between a proper PCB and a prototyping board!
So I'd suggest getting the cap as close to the load as possible. Use two caps to be sure (ceramic or foil, maybe 10n or 100n) and a 10u one in parallel. The small one to get the high frequencies, the bigger one to get the slower stuff. Consider putting a small resistor in series to the load:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
This way you get a nice little filter... you can also replace the resistor with an inductor.
Will it be worth it? That's where we enter speculation territory. Maybe? Filtering is often done "just to be sure", "because someone has solved a problem like this in the past" and "because we've always done it that way". Also "because if it doesn't help, it doesn't hurt"...

Thanks for the suggestion. Sorry, by "as close to the load," you mean the HX711 or load cell? In my perfboards, the capacitors, the ones you suggested, are right next to the VCC and GND of the HX711 (which goes on top of those round female pin headers). Another question: why do I need a resistor?

@wyc yes, as close to the HX711. What we do with the capacitors is basically creating a filter. But an filter with just a cpacitance is not filtering much. The filter constant is defined by the impedance of the source and the capacitance. Source impedance is normally pretty low so the cut off frequency gets relly hight (and since we don't know the input impedance we're just quessing. With the resistor we can get the cut off frequency down and controllable.

Today I learned what a "cargo cult" is.
I second the "because if it doesen't help it doesn't hurt"

@kruemi Sorry, so the left circle (Vcc 5V) is the HX711 and the right circle (MCU) is the ESP32-C3 (where my circuit is getting power from)?

@wyc more generaly: left is the part that you want to protect from the noise of the right part... I've switched the Caps around btw because you want to have the small cap closer to the noise source...

@kruemi Okay, thanks again for the advice. I'll try this out.
